# How to assign a value depending on two conditions including column names. (add environmental variable to tracking data)

Tags: r, gps, environment-variables, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I have a data frame (track) with the position (longitude - Latitude) and date (number of the day in the year) of tracking point for different animals and an other data frame (var) which gives a the mean temperature for every day of the year in different locations.

I would like to add a new column TEMP to my data frame (Track) where the value would be from (var) and correspond to the date and GPS location of each tracking points in (track).

Here are a really simple subset of my data and what I would like to obtain.

```
track = data.frame(
  animals=c(1,1,1,2,2),
  Longitude=c(117,116,117,117,116),
  Latitude=c(18,20,20,18,20),
  Day=c(1,3,4,1,5))


Var = data.frame(
  Longitude=c(117,117,116,116),
  Latitude=c(18,20,18,20),
  Day1=c(22,23,24,21),
  Day2=c(21,28,27,29),
  Day3=c(12,13,14,11),
  Day4=c(17,19,20,23),
  Day5=c(32,33,34,31)
  )

TrackPlusVar = data.frame(
  animals=c(1,1,1,2,2),
  Longitude=c(117,116,117,117,116),
  Latitude=c(18,20,20,18,20),
  Day=c(1,3,4,1,5),
  Temp= c(22,11,19,22,31)
    )
```

I've no idea how to assign the value from the same date and GPS location as it is a column name. Any idea would be very useful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `dplyr` and `tidyr` approach.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# reshape table Var
Var %>% 
  gather(Day,Temp,-Longitude, -Latitude) %>%
  mutate(Day = as.numeric(gsub("Day","",Day))) -> Var2

# join tables
track %>% left_join(Var2, by=c("Longitude", "Latitude", "Day"))

#   animals Longitude Latitude Day Temp
# 1       1       117       18   1   22
# 2       1       116       20   3   11
# 3       1       117       20   4   19
# 4       2       117       18   1   22
# 5       2       116       20   5   31
```

If the process that creates your tables makes sure that all your cases belong to both tables, then you can use `inner_join` instead of `left_join` to make the process faster.

If you're still not happy with the speed you can use a `data.table` join process to check if it is faster, like:

```
library(data.table)

Var2 = setDT(Var2, key = c("Longitude", "Latitude", "Day"))
track = setDT(track, key = c("Longitude", "Latitude", "Day"))

Var2[track][order(animals,Day)]

#    Longitude Latitude Day Temp animals
# 1:       117       18   1   22       1
# 2:       116       20   3   11       1
# 3:       117       20   4   19       1
# 4:       117       18   1   22       2
# 5:       116       20   5   31       2
```

Comment: data.table's purpose/adv. isn't only its speed. It needn't be just a substitute under "slow" situations. And you're deep copying both `Var2` and `track`.

Comment: You're right (x2) @Arun. I just presented it in that way only because I started with `dplyr` to create `Var2`. Will also update to create data.tables using `setDT`.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. It's just that people who'd read this post later would've a very different approach to reading it than you intended.